# How to setup service locator to test view models in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to write some unit test for my view models and i'm running into the following issue. 
Part of the problem is i might be using the service locator incorrectly, but here it goes.

Here's my code (using MVVM Light IOC to register my repository):

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand ...;
    private RelayCommand ...;
    private ObservableCollection<Test> _list;
    private IRepository<Test> _testRepository;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        //Get the repository
        _tenderRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository<Test>>();

        //do a get on the repository and load it onto a list
        LoadTestData()
    }
            ...
}
```

There are several public properties and public methods that I would like to unit test for this view model ... so i'm setting it up this way:

```
[TestFixture]
public class VMTests
{
    TestViewModel _vm;

    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAllFixtures()
    {
        _vm = new TestViewModel();
    }

    [Test()]
    public void PublicMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error from the test engine saying that "**ServiceLocationProvider must be set**" when i attempted to run the test. Does this means that I have to mock (or create a test provider), register it in the test project before creating selecting the vm instance in the test project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
  [SetUp]
  public void RunBeforeAllFixtures()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            _vm = new TestViewModel();

        }
```

and also mocking and registering  IRepository 'Test'